# How many divisors does $n!$ have?

Tags: number-theory, limits, prime-numbers, divisibility, analytic-number-theory

Let $d(n!)$ be the number of divisors of $n!$. I observed that graph of $\log(d(n!)$ is similar to that of $\pi(x)$, the number of prime not exceeding $x$ except for a scaling factor. In other words, the following limit must exist:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log(d(n!))}{\pi(n)} \approx 1.26
$$

**Question**: What is known about the number of divisors of $n!$? Can it be proved or disproved?

Comment: The sequence $d(n!)$ is OEIS A027423: https://oeis.org/A027423 .

Comment: I know you're very well aware that if $n$ is a positive integer, $n!$ is divisible by every prime between 0 and $n$. For example, $\pi(10) = 4$, so $\sigma_0(10!) > 4$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A short argument of Erdős et al. (see $\S$2 of the cited article) shows that

$$\log d(n!) \sim \frac{c_0 \log (n!)}{\log^2 \log (n!)} \left[1 + O\left(\frac{\log\log\log (n!)}{\log\log (n!)}\right)\right],$$
where $$\color{#df0000}{c_0 = \int_1^\infty \frac{\log (\lfloor t \rfloor + 1) \,dt}{t^2} = \sum_{k = 2}^\infty \frac{\log k}{k (k - 1)} = 1.25775\!\ldots }.$$
Applying Stirling's Approximation then gives that the leading term of the above series approximation is
$$\frac{c_0 n}{\log n} + O\left(\frac{n \log \log n}{(\log n)^2}\right) .$$
On the other hand, the Prime Number Theorem says that $$\pi(n) \sim \frac{n}{\log n} + o \left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right),$$
so $$\color{#df0000}{\boxed{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log d(n!)}{\pi(n)} = c_0}} .$$

> Erdös P., Graham S. W., Ivić A., Pomerance C. (1996) ["On the number of divisors of n!."](http://people.cst.cmich.edu/graha1sw/pub/papers/divfactorial.pdf) In: Berndt B. C., Diamond H. G., Hildebrand A. J. (eds.) *Analytic Number Theory*. Progress in Mathematics **138** Birkhäuser Boston.

**Remark** In fact, we can compute higher asymptotics of the ratio using the formulae of Erdős et al. (and a better bound on the remainder of the above approximation to $\pi(n)$), e.g.,
$$\frac{\log d(n!)}{\pi(n)} \sim c_0 + \frac{c_1}{\log n} + O\left(\frac{1}{\log^2 n}\right), $$ where
$$c_1 := \int_1^\infty \frac{\log(\lfloor t \rfloor + 1) \log t \,dt}{t^2} = 2.11412\!\ldots .$$

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  Very interesting.

Comment: There are $8$ $\log$s in Erdos's RHS estimate !!!!!!

Comment: @NilotpalKantiSinha There's an old joke, "What sound does a drowning number theorist make?" "$\log\log\log\ldots$."